# Can "mdfind" search for phrases and not just unordered words?

Tags: terminal, search, spotlight

Is there a way to search for an exact phrase using the `mdfind` utility? For example, I created two text documents titled "test1" and "test2". The contents of "test1" are:

> I love Apple

And the contents of "test2" are:

> Apple love I

When I type this in terminal (I placed both files in ~/Documents):

> mdfind "I love Apple" -onlyin ~/Documents

I get:

> ~/Documents/test1.txt
>   ~/Documents/test2.txt

How would I search for the exact phrase "I love Apple" so `mdfind` only returns results containing those words in that order (in this case only "test1.txt")?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes like so:

```
mdfind \"I love Apple\" -onlyin ~/Documents
```

This results in just the one document being found:

```
~/Documents/test1.txt
```

Without escaping them, I don't think the quotes actually get passed to the `mdfind` command, they're just interpreted by your shell to say that `I love Apple` is a single argument. With the backslash-escaping, the argument then includes the quote characters.

Answer (score 7):

The double quotes can also be placed inside single quotes:

```
mdfind '"exact phrase"'
```

This would search only in the contents:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemTextContent=="*exact phrase*"'
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked too, but drfrogsplat answered first.